# how to update individual array element in side array of object in setState in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add an array element inside the object but if I type text  all the text boxes show the text and the text is added only to the first element . even if i added text in second and third text box it is addding into the first tag list plz help me how to fix it

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const synonym = [
    { id: 1, keyword: "Caffeine", synonyms: ["Coffee", "Espresso"] },
    { id: 2, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: ["Sleeping", "Fatigue"] },
    { id: 3, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: [""] }
  ];
  const [mysynonyms, setSynonyms] = useState(() => synonym);
  const [addTagValue, setAddTagValue] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAddTagValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSynonyms((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === 0) {
          return { item, synonyms: [...item.synonyms, addTagValue] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
    setAddTagValue("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mysynonyms.map((item, cid) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{item.keyword}</p>

            {item.synonyms.map((item, cid) => (
              <span
                style={{ border: "1px solid red", padding: "1px 1px 5px 7px" }}
              >
                {item} x
              </span>
            ))}
            <div>
              <input
                value={addTagValue}
                className="form-control bg-color2 text-color7 border-end-0 fs-14 fw-bold"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button onClick={handleClick}>add tag</button>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: According to the `handleClick` function, you add `addTagValue` only to the first item of the `mysynonyms`. You'd better to save the `index` of the edited synonym item.

Comment: Do you have something like `CodeSandbox`?

Comment: yes i have please check this link thank you so much for your time https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-gwen-f79nrb?file=/src/App.js:0-1545

Answer (score 1):

Here are my updates.

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const synonym = [
    { id: 1, keyword: "Caffeine", synonyms: ["Coffee", "Espresso"] },
    { id: 2, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: ["Sleeping", "Fatigue"] },
    { id: 3, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: [""] }
  ];
  const [mysynonyms, setSynonyms] = useState(() => synonym);
  const [addTagValue, setAddTagValue] = useState([]);
  const [editingIndex, setEditingIndex] = useState(0);  // THIS CONTAINS THE INDEX OF EDITING ITEM
  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    setAddTagValue(e.target.value);
    setEditingIndex(index)  // SAVE THE INDEX OF EDITING ITEM
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSynonyms((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === editingIndex) {  // IF CURRENT ITEM IS EDITING, ADD VALUE TO THIS ITEM
          return { ...item, synonyms: [...item.synonyms, addTagValue] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
    setAddTagValue("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mysynonyms.map((synonymItem, synonymIndex) => {
        return (
          <div key={synonymIndex}>
            <p>{synonymItem.keyword}</p>

            {synonymItem.synonyms.map((item, cid) => (
              <span
                key={cid}
                style={{ border: "1px solid red", padding: "1px 1px 5px 7px" }}
              >
                {item} x
              </span>
            ))}
            <div>
              <input
                value={synonymIndex === editingIndex? addTagValue : ""}
                className="form-control bg-color2 text-color7 border-end-0 fs-14 fw-bold"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, synonymIndex)}
              />
              <button onClick={handleClick}>add tag</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And don't forget to use the `key` attribute for the mapping `React Element`.

You can check the running code in my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-robinson-w492x0).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated few in your code

```
<button onClick={() => handleClick(cid)}>add tag</button>
```

and your function

```
const handleClick = (tagIndex) => {
    setSynonyms((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === tagIndex) {
          return { item, synonyms: [...item.synonyms, addTagValue] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
    setAddTagValue("");
  };
```

Please check your coding function as per below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const synonym = [
    { id: 1, keyword: "Caffeine", synonyms: ["Coffee", "Espresso"] },
    { id: 2, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: ["Sleeping", "Fatigue"] },
    { id: 3, keyword: "Drowsiness", synonyms: [""] }
  ];
  const [mysynonyms, setSynonyms] = useState(() => synonym);
  const [addTagValue, setAddTagValue] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAddTagValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = (tagIndex) => {
    setSynonyms((prevValue) => {
      return prevValue.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === tagIndex) {
          return { item, synonyms: [...item.synonyms, addTagValue] };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    });
    setAddTagValue("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {mysynonyms.map((item, cid) => {
        return (
          <>
            <p>{item.keyword}</p>

            {item.synonyms.map((item, cid) => (
              <span
                style={{ border: "1px solid red", padding: "1px 1px 5px 7px" }}
              >
                {item} x
              </span>
            ))}
            <div>
              <input
                value={addTagValue}
                className="form-control bg-color2 text-color7 border-end-0 fs-14 fw-bold"
                type="text"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <button onClick={() => handleClick(cid)}>add tag</button>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```